# What is Curvature of eye lens?

Tags: optics, refraction, lenses, vision

I wanted to know what do we mean by "curvature of eye lens", is it the reciprocal of $r$ i.e $c=1/r$ or is it synonymous to radius of curvature of the eye lens. Moreover how does aperture relate to the curvature of eye lens, is curvature of eye lens dependent on the aperture?
Moreover a definition of curvature of eye lens stated that: curvature of eye lens is the arc of the eye lens but isn't this similar to the definition of aperture of lens which is the effective diameter of circular outline of the spherical lens.

[image]

in this diagram, is the perpendicular distance A, the aperture and the circular outline distance the curvature?

Comment: I think that the curvature of the eye lens is not a significant quantity at least not directly, what matters more is the radius of the curvature as this would determine the focal length of the eye lens self - and by "not directly" I mean that the shape of the curvature defines the radius after all -, which in turns would determine the position of the formed image.

I can help rewriting the definition, is that the curvature of the eye is the shape by which the surface of the eye "curves", that is what it does mean by the arc. The aperture means the opening or a hole through which light enters